# Installing Polymer for the first time

Tags: polymer

I Right-click or CTRL+click on the icon-toggle/demo folder and choose Run according to [these instructions](http://www.code-labs.io/codelabs/polymer-first-elements/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fpolymer-summit&viewga=UA-39334307-12#2) and I get:

Unable to deploy the current selection; please select an application to deploy.

Comment: I have been successfully using Polymer for a while. When I tried to do those code labs I remember there was some issue with it that might very well be the same one you describe. I recommend you file an official issue report at their Github and include a link back to this SO question. You can also visit their Slack site and ask a question. Also backlink to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same issue. All i t took to fix it was restarting the Chrome Dev Editor.